# Prove that two vertices of a triangle and the feet of the altitudes to the sides adjacent to the third vertex can be inscribed in a cicle.

Tags: geometry

I'm a little confused on the what the drawing of this would look like.

Prove that two vertices of a triangle and the feet of the altitudes to the sides adjacent to the third vertex can be inscribed in a cicle.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Consider cyclic quadrilateral theorems.

Comment: The Inscribed Angle Theorem (more specifically, Thales' Theorem) makes light work of this.